# How to Highlight long text fields in solr 4.0?

Tags: solr, highlighting

I have field named “Fulltext” in solr which has more than 50,000 characters. I want to highlight the search keyword for that field. I have set

```
 f.Fulltext.hl.snippets=30
    f.Fulltext.hl.fragsize =50000
    h1.MaxAnalyzedChars = 100000;
```

The problem I am facing is, the whole document in “Fulltext” field is either not getting highlighted or fully produced. It’s producing only partial document. For all other fields highlighting is working good. I think since this field has too many characters it is not working? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Your setting of `f.Fulltext.hl.fragsize=50000` is limiting the size of the highlighting snippet to only 50,000 characters and you have stated that your field is longer than 50,000 characters. In order to get the results that you are looking for, you should set `f.Fulltext.hl.fragsize=0` (indicating unlimited) along with your `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=100000`. See the [hl.maxAnalyzedChars](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.maxAnalyzedChars) reference on the Solr Wiki.

Please note that the above will work only with the original Highlighter. If you are using the FastVectorHighlighter, you should see the notes for [hl.fragSize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) reference on the Solr wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are case-sensitive.

```
h1.MaxAnalyzedChars //won't work

hl.maxAnalyzedChars //will (also there was a typo: hl instead of h1...)
```

Setting

```
hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1
```

will indicate unlimited.